# Flutter Unity Widget IOs crashes sometimes

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, progressive-web-apps

I am using flutter web and the user has to download the Web App as a standalone(PWA) App. I lso use the [flutter_unity_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) for my application. I have added logs everywhere in the code which sends crashes to my Database.
Somehow for some IOs Users when loading a level it shows the unity loading screen for a few seconds and then a blank screen and they get back to the level_select screen which is done in Flutter. What could be problems that this only happens on IOs devices. I do not have any problems with my Android devices and my Windows PC. I read that IOs is very strict on memory/ram handling. But it appears that my app is not using that much memory/ram. Here is the app, it is a web app which you have to install on your device, because i am using it for my master thesis, and i can not upload it to the App Store, due to some restrictions from my professor. https://felpower.github.io/ Also it is german only, but you can basically skip the survey at the beginning, the only thing is you have to enter an age between 18 and 120

Here is the code where i try/catch the UnityCreated and the SceneLoaded

```
void onUnitySceneLoaded(SceneLoaded? scene) {
    try {
      if (scene != null) {
        FirebaseStore.sendError("onUnitySceneLoadedNoError", stacktrace: scene.name);
      } else {
        FirebaseStore.sendError("onUnitySceneLoadedSceneNotLoaded", stacktrace: "Scene not loaded");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      FirebaseStore.sendError("onUnitySceneLoaded", stacktrace: e.toString());
    }
  }

  // Callback that connects the created controller to the unity controller
  void onUnityCreated(controller) {
    try {
      controller.resume();
      unityWidgetController = controller;
    } catch (e) {
      FirebaseStore.sendError("onUnityCreated", stacktrace: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/NTBAXnggM6c) where you can see the error happening

I received this error log from a user, but i can not find out what the errors are, i asked ChatGPT, but the answers from chatGPT do not make a lot of sense to me [image: IOS Error Log]